# Selecting all nodes up to a row with a condition using XPath

Tags: html, xml, xpath

Given this HTML:

```html
<!-- ...similar content... -->
<tr>
    <td colspan="3" class="pcipgSubHeader"><b>November 2021</b></td>
</tr>
<tr class="pcipgAddTopPadding">
    <td></td>
    <td width="40px"><b>Qty</b></td>
    <td width="80px"><b>Each</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="text-align: left; padding-left: 5px;"></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>~CA $12.5669</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="text-align: left; padding-left: 5px;"></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>~CA $16.4506</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="text-align: left; padding-left: 5px;"></td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>~CA $17.5517</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="text-align: left; padding-left: 5px;"></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>~CA $24.0738</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="text-align: left; padding-left: 5px;"></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>~CA $24.7314</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="text-align: left; padding-left: 5px;"></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>~CA $25.4772</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="text-align: left; padding-left: 5px;"></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>~CA $33.8775</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="text-align: left; padding-left: 5px;"></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>~CA $35.3709</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td width="80px">Total Lots:</td>
    <td><b>8</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Total Qty:</td>
    <td><b>11</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Min Price:</td>
    <td><b>CA $12.5669</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Avg Price:</td>
    <td><b>CA $23.7625</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Qty Avg Price:</td>
    <td><b>CA $22.0686</b></td>
</tr>
<tr class="pcipgAddBottomPadding">
    <td></td>
    <td>Max Price:</td>
    <td><b>CA $35.3709</b></td>
</tr>
<!-- ...similar content... -->
```

and with a reference to `.` being the first row shown (though not the first row looking like that), I need to select all subsequent rows up to and excluding the first row that has a `td` with a `colspan`. This does not work:

```xml
./following-sibling::tr[preceding-sibling::tr[td[@colspan]]]
```

In a C#/HTML Agility Pack XPath expression, it doesn't stop at the desired row, and runs all the way to the end of the parent node.

Answer (score 0):

This XPath,

```xml
//tr[td/@class='pcipgSubHeader']
 /following-sibling::tr[not(td/@colspan) and
                        count(preceding-sibling::tr/td/@colspan) = 1]
```

will select all `tr` elements starting at the one that has the noted `td` child and progressing through all sibling `tr` elements until and excluding the next `tr` element that has a `td` child with a `colspan` attribute.

Or, if as stated in the question it may be assumed that the targeted start `tr` element is the current node:

```xml
./following-sibling::tr[not(td/@colspan) and
                        count(preceding-sibling::tr/td/@colspan) = 1]
```

Comment: This got me closer. The problem is that the `count` function seems to be counting not from `.`, but from the beginning of all of the prior siblings of `.`. There's similar content to what I showed both before and after the excerpt. I only got the expected results when I used `count() = 3`. How do you make `count` only count from `.` onward?

Comment: Then you've underspecified the criteria intended to delimited the desired range in your example.  Fix that by posting a true [mcve] that's properly representative of your actual problem.